# Opening the Table from the Database

Tags: mysql

Am new to MySQL 5.1

In MySQL Where i can i find the Database & Table....

I was attached one database in MYSQL through odbc connectivity, How can i get that table values from the attached database. And also i want to create a table from the database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next SQL statements should be helpful: `SHOW DATABASES`, `SHOW TABLES`, `USE %databasename%`.

Use `SHOW DATABASES` in order to retrieve the list of available databases inside the RDBMS MySQL.

Call `USE %databasename%` to use the database `%databasename%` as the default one for the subsequent manipulations.

And, finally, `SHOW TABLES` can be used to retrieve the list of tables current database contains.